# Remove Personal Options section from Profile

Tags: profiles

I want to hide/remove the Personal Options in the **Your Profile** (`wp-admin/profile.php`) admin page.

I am aware that solutions for this exist, but I they use jQuery to do hide this section. This works, but when a user has JavaScript disabled in their browser, it will show up again. Therefore it is not a proper way to remove Personal Options.

Is there a way to remove the Personal Options section from the HTML source of the page? This means no jQuery or CSS hacks, or core file modification.

Comment: Just to add, if a user has JavaScript disabled, there's a lot more they won't be able to use in Wordpress. But still, doing it server-side is much better when possible :)

Comment: Be careful - see answer: **https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/162277/33667**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove these fields from the 'Profile' section?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32785/how-to-remove-these-fields-from-the-profile-section)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
// removes the `profile.php` admin color scheme options
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
  /**
   * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
   */
  function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

Also, don't forget to mark your previous questions as solved :)

Comment: this is awesome, but how do i make it work for WP 3.4? only the color scheme picker is removed. probably bec i can't seem to find the files `admin_head-profile.php` and `admin_footer-profile.php` in the core. ideas? thanks much.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? I just used this on a new installation and it worked OK. Note you have to edit above code if you're using some other language. Also, here's some info about `admin_head-profile.php` and `admin_footer-profile.php`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions

Comment: @CorvanNoorloos Thanks for this, is there any way to leave the option to allow them to check if they want to show the toolbar or not?

Comment: my current version 6.0.2 uses h2 not h3, may need to update `preg_replace` for that

Answer (score 10):

Accepted answer is not working with 4.8

Here comes an up to date and simplified code that should work with any version:

```
        // removes admin color scheme options

        remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

        //Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.

        add_action( 'admin_head', function () {

            ob_start( function( $subject ) {

                $subject = preg_replace( '#<h[0-9]>'.__("Personal Options").'</h[0-9]>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
                return $subject;
            });
        });

        add_action( 'admin_footer', function(){

            ob_end_flush();
        });
```

Comment: +1 but same problem as with accepted answer, the string needs to be localized for it to work with non english laguages.

Comment: @MarkKaplun thats right! I made the change.

Answer (score 6):

Was just trying to figure this out and came across this answer.  The above code by Cor van doesn't work anymore, but with a slight change of the add_action, it can.

All you need to do is change the last two lines from:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

to

```
add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-user-edit.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

So, the final code would look something like:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
  /**
   * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
   */
  function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-user-edit.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

Comment: Nice follow up, this change to the original code worked perfectly.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I remove more <h3> elements? What modifications of the above code do I need?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the comment from @Per I got it working for 4.5.2

```
    // removes admin color scheme options
    remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

    if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
        /**
        * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
        */
        function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
            $subject = preg_replace( '#<h2>Personal Options</h2>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
            return $subject;
        }

        function cor_profile_subject_start() {
            ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
        }

        function cor_profile_subject_end() {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );`
```

Answer (score 2):

Update for 3.9, the following works:

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my CSS solution, tested in Wordpress 4.9.8

```
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
add_action( 'admin_head', function(){
    ob_start(); ?>
    <style>
        #your-profile > h2,
        .user-rich-editing-wrap,
        .user-syntax-highlighting-wrap,
        .user-comment-shortcuts-wrap,
        .user-admin-bar-front-wrap {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <?php ob_end_flush();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to clarify that the code will not work for localized versions of WordPress, because of the hardcoded `Personal Options` string. I cannot think of any easy solution here, but suggestions are welcome.

I would have added this as a comment, but I haven't got enough reputation to add a comment.

I also take this opportunity to re-paste the whole code updated for WordPress version 3.9.

Here it is:

```
// removes the `profile.php` admin color scheme options
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
  /**
   * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
   */
  function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

Again, if you know in advance what the language of your WP installation will be, change the `Personal Options` string to the localized version of your language, for example in Italian you will replace it with `Impostazioni personali`.

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
$subject = preg_replace( '#<h3>'.__("Personal Options").'</h3>.+?/table>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
```

in the cor_remove_personal_options function, it is localized as well.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found this solution on: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-simplify-wordpress-profiles-by-removing-personal-options/?ptm=c&utm_expid=3606929-108.O6f5ypXuTg-XPCV9sY1yrw.2

```
function hide_personal_options(){ 
    echo "\n" . '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(\'form#your-profile > h3:first\').hide(); $(\'form#your-profile > 
    table:first\').hide(); $(\'form#your-profile\').show(); });</script>' . "\n"; 
} 
add_action('admin_head','hide_personal_options');
```

If you want to be more specific or remove more you should have a look over here: https://isabelcastillo.com/hide-personal-options-wordpress-admin-profile

You can just add those lines into the function.

Comment: Removing it with Javascript is never a good practice...

Answer (score 0):

I remove only title and use CSS to hide first table...

For me, in 2023, this work:

```
 // removes admin color scheme options
    remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );

    if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
        /**
        * Removes the leftover 'Visual Editor', 'Keyboard Shortcuts' and 'Toolbar' options.
        */
        function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
           $subject = preg_replace( '#<h[0-9]>'.__("Personal Options").'</h[0-9]>#s', '<style>#your-profile>.form-table {display:none} #your-profile>.form-table ~ .form-table {display:block}</style>', $subject, 1 );
            return $subject;
        }

        function cor_profile_subject_start() {
            ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
        }

        function cor_profile_subject_end() {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_head', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```