# remove admin bar show hide option from profile settings

Tags: profiles, admin-bar

Do not misunderstood.

I am trying to remove/disable Show toolbar option (not talking about hide/disable admin bar) but talking about The Option into Profile Settings.

I tried to search but in all I found only how to disable admin bar from front and back but nowhere I found how to remove the check-boxes from profile settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fields are hard coded there is nog filter or action to disable it.
You could hide it with CSS....

If you want you could replace the entirely page with a different one you custom create.

Comment: Actually I was looking proper and technical solution but css hack is also fine for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@pixelngrain , Maybe this is what you where looking for, this part of code will at least hide the *Personal Options*.

```
function hide_personal_options(){
echo "\n" . 
'<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
$(\'form#your-profile > h3:first\').hide(); 
$(\'form#your-profile > table:first\').hide(); 
$(\'form#your-profile\').show(); });
</script>' . 
"\n"; 
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_personal_options');
```

This in functions.php works like a charm for me. Code found here : [Remove personal options](http://wpdojo.net/tag/hide-visual-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer provided to the question [Remove Personal Options section from Profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/remove-personal-options-section-from-profile), you can remove the entire block of 'Personal Options' from the profile/user edit screens.  By adapting the approach in the top answer there, you can specifically target the Toolbar option using:

```
 //Removes the 'Show Toolbar' option.
  function as_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $subject = preg_replace( '#<tr class="show-admin-bar">.+?/tr>#s', '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function as_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'as_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function as_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'as_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'as_profile_subject_end' );

add_action( 'admin_head-user-edit.php', 'as_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-user-edit.php', 'as_profile_subject_end' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide the checkbox on the profile page based on current_user_can, this appears to work:

```
function yourprefix_hide_option_show_admin_bar_user_profile_page() { 

    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_product' ) ) {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">.show-admin-bar { display: none; }</style>
    <?php 
    }

}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'yourprefix_hide_option_show_admin_bar_user_profile_page' );
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the plugin Theme-My-Login installed and was able to do this by opening  wp-content\plugins\theme-my-login\templates\profile-form.php and removing these lines near the top on line 18 or 19:

```
<table class="tml-form-table">
            <?php if ( apply_filters( 'show_admin_bar', true ) ) : ?>
                <tr class="tml-user-admin-bar-front-wrap">
                    <th><label for="admin_bar_front"><?php _e( 'Toolbar', 'theme-my-login' )?></label></th>
                    <td>
                        <label for="admin_bar_front"><input type="checkbox" name="admin_bar_front" id="admin_bar_front" value="1"<?php checked( _get_admin_bar_pref( 'front', $profileuser->ID ) ); ?> />
                        <?php _e( 'Show Toolbar when viewing site', 'theme-my-login' ); ?></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php do_action( 'personal_options', $profileuser ); ?>
            </table>
```

This most likely will need to be redone every time the plugin is updated.