# Edit profile fields with TML

Tags: profiles

I am using TML for my site and I have activated themed profiles so members will not have access to wp dashboard and admin bar.

My question is whether anyone could explain to me how do I edit sections on profile page because at the moment it has a lot of different unnecessary sections and fields.

Thank you so much in advance and I look forward to your reply.

Comment: You have to remove unwanted profile fields as described in these topics https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32785/how-to-remove-these-fields-from-the-profile-section?rq=1 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/remove-personal-options-section-from-profile?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

copy the profile-form.php file located at template folder inside theme-my-login plugin directory to your theme folder, then you can edit all the look and feel and fields of the profile section.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. If I would like to remove below field, in the profile-form.php, what codes should I remove or edit?

I look forward to hearing from you.

PERSONAL OPTIONS
– toolbar

Comment: Look at Vinod Delvi's comment, you can use Wordpress's hooks to remove unwanted field, it's a little tricky but it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. If I want to put the code suggested in the link here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/remove-personal-options-section-from-profile?rq=1 (the one with a tick), where in profile-form.php should I put? Should I replace it or just paste it at the end? For replacement, from where exactly to where should I do so? Looking forward to your response.